# EF Core Cascading Deletes for Speed?

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I'm working on an established (but changeable, assuming existing data survives any changes) code base and investigating some very slow deletes.  So far I've only succeeded in making things worse, so here we are. I've backed out most of my attempted changes below to avoid adding extra unnecessary confusion.

There's a data class ProductDefinition which models a same-object hierarchy similar to e.g. a folder structure: every PD (except the root) will have one parent, but like a folder can have multiple children.

```
public class ProductDefinition
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    // each tree of PDs should have a 'head' which will have no parent
    // but most will have a ParentPDID and corresponding ParentPD
    public virtual ProductDefinition ParentProductDefinition { get; set; } 
    public int? ParentProductDefinitionId { get; set; }  

    public virtual List<ProductDefinition> ProductDefinitions { get; set; } 
                                    = new List<ProductDefinition>();

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // etc. Fields. Nothing so large you'd expect speed issues

}
```

The corresponding table has been specifically declared in the Context

```
public DbSet<ProductDefinition> ProductDefinitions { get; set; }
```

Along with a Fluent API relationship defined on Context.OnModelCreating

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductDefinition>()
            .HasMany(productDefinition => productDefinition.ProductDefinitions)
            .WithOne(childPd => childPd.ParentProductDefinition)
            .HasForeignKey(childPd => childPd.ParentProductDefinitionId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(productDefinition => productDefinition.ID);
```

It looks like an attempt has already been made to firm up deletion in the ProductDefinitionManager class

```
public static async Task ForceDelete(int ID, ProductContext context)
    {
        // wrap the recursion in a save so that it only happens once
        await ForceDeleteNoSave(ID, context);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

And

```
private static async Task ForceDeleteNoSave(int ID, ProductContext context)
    {
        var pd = await context.ProductDefinitions
                             .AsNoTracking()
                             .Include(x => x.ProductDefinitions)
                             .SingleAsync(x => x.ID == ID);

        if (pd.ProductDefinitions != null && pd.ProductDefinitions.Count != 0)
        {
            var childIDs = pd.ProductDefinitions.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();

            // delete the children recursively
            foreach (var child in childIDs)
            {
                // EDITED HERE TO CORRECTLY REFLECT THE CURRENT CODE BASE
                await ForceDeleteNoSave(child, context);
            }
        }

        // delete the PD
        // mark Supplier as edited
        var supplier = await context.Suppliers.FindAsync(pd.SupplierID);
        supplier.Edited = true;

        // reload with tracking
        pd = await context.ProductDefinitions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID == ID);
        context.ProductDefinitions.Remove(pd);
    }
```

At present, the above solution 'works', but:

a) takes over 2 minutes to complete
b) Seems to be giving the React front end a 502 error (but see above). Certainly the FE is claiming a 502

My primary question is: is there a way to improve the deletion speed, e.g. by defining a cascading delete in FluentAPI (my attempt hit an issue when trying to apply the migration)?  But I welcome any discussion of what might be causing the FE to report Bad Gateway.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is self refencing relationship and cascade delete cannot be used due to "multiple cascade paths" issue - limitation of SqlServer (and probably other) database (Oracle has no such issue).

The best way to handle in the databases which does not support "multiple cascade paths" is to use database trigger ("instead of delete").

But let say we want to handle it via client code in EF Core. The question is how to load effectively a recursive tree like structure (another not easy task in EF Core due to lack of recursive query support).

The problem with your code is that it uses *depth first* algorithm, which executes a lot of database queries. The more appropriate and performant way is to use *breath first* algorithm - in simple words, loading the items by *level*. This way the number of the database queries would be the maximum depth in the tree, which is way less than the number of the elements.

One way to implement that is to start with a query with initial filter applies, and then use `SelectMany` to get the next level (each `SelectMany` adds a join to the previous query). The process ends when the query does not return data:

```
public static async Task ForceDelete(int ID, ProductContext context)
{
    var items = new List<ProductDefinition>();

    // Collect the items by level    
    var query = context.ProductDefinitions.Where(e => e.ID == ID);
    while (true)
    {
        var nextLevel = await query
            .Include(e => e.Supplier)
            .ToListAsync();
        if (nextLevel.Count == 0) break;
        items.AddRange(nextLevel);
        query = query.SelectMany(e => e.ProductDefinitions);
    }

    foreach (var item in items)
        item.Supplier.Edited = true;

    context.RemoveRange(items);

    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Note that the executed queries eager load the related `Supplier` so it ca easily be updated.

Once the items are collected, they are simply marked for deleting via `RemoveRange` method. The order doesn't matter because EF Core will apply the commands by the dependency order anyway.

Another way to collect the items is to use the `ID`s from the previous level as a filter (SQL `IN`):

```
// Collect the items by level    
Expression<Func<ProductDefinition, bool>> filter = e => e.ID == ID;
while (true)
{
    var nextLevel = await context.ProductDefinitions
        .Include(e => e.Supplier)
        .Where(filter)
        .ToListAsync();
    if (nextLevel.Count == 0) break;
    items.AddRange(nextLevel);
    var parentIds = nextLevel.Select(e => e.ID);
    filter = e => parentIds.Contains(e.ParentProductDefinitionId.Value);
}
```

I like more the former. The drawback is that EF Core generates a huge table name aliases, and also it could hit some SQL join number limitation in case of big depth. The later has no depth limitation, but might have issues with big `IN` clause. You should check which one is more appropriate for your case.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It is a bit hard to understand exactly why this is slow. How big is the data structure etc.

The first thing that springs to my eye when I look at the above code is the following:

```
public static async Task ForceDelete(int ID, ProductContext context)
{
    // wrap the recursion in a save so that it only happens once
    await ForceDeleteNoSave(ID, context);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

This method is called recursively but every time you are done with a bunch of children it will call `context.SaveChagesAsync()`. Which means when you run the code you will get multiple saves and multiple calls to the database.

This seems like an anti-pattern, because if your program crashes half-way through it has already deleted some of the children.

Instead have an `InitForceDelete()` that in the end will call the `context.SaveChangesAsync()` so it is all done in one operation.

Something like this:

```
public static async Task InitForceDelete(int ID, ProductContext context)
{
    // wrap the recursion in a save so that it only happens once
    await ForceDeleteNoSave(ID, context);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}

private static async Task ForceDeleteNoSave(int ID, ProductContext context)
{
    var pd = await context.ProductDefinitions
                         .AsNoTracking()
                         .Include(x => x.ProductDefinitions)
                         .SingleAsync(x => x.ID == ID);

    if (pd.ProductDefinitions != null && pd.ProductDefinitions.Count != 0)
    {
        var childIDs = pd.ProductDefinitions.Select(x => x.ID).ToList();

        // delete the children recursively
        foreach (var child in childIDs)
        {
            await ForceDeleteNoSave(child, context);
        }
    }
    var supplier = await context.Suppliers.FindAsync(pd.SupplierID);
    supplier.Edited = true;

    // reload with tracking
    pd = await context.ProductDefinitions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.ID == ID);
    context.ProductDefinitions.Remove(pd);
}
```

Now secondly you should try to inspect the sql that is being executed on your SQL server. You should be able to find the execution plans triggered by your LINQ statements and see if the SQL is completely crazy. Maybe your code is executing one call per `ProductDefinition` which would make it super slow.

I am sorry I cannot be more precise, but from the code you have presented it is hard to give direct pointers except for your constant call to `context.SaveChagesAsync()`.

Comment: Hi Kristian and thanks for your response. I will have to amend the code snippet used, as I did already spot and correct the issue you identified re nested SaveChangesAsync().  Actually with the code as you just got to see it, I was getting 'expected to change one row but changed zero rows' exceptions.

Comment: Regarding the object itself, it's tiny. If I were performing this operation on an Excel spreadsheet or in SSMS, I would expect it to take under a second.  In fact, elsewhere in the application I'm avoiding "get this, now get that, now that thing" 
 bottlenecks by just sucking in the whole table.  Investigation here suggests that when we SaveChangesAsync(), EF is sequentially loading each row and performing the delete.  It seems this is also the case if RemoveRange is used, although at some point last night I seem to recall reading about a 'single hit' version of RemoveRange...?

Comment: @technorabble I think the big issue here is that you are doing a recursive delete of an undefined depth. This is very hard for EF to effectively translate into effective SQL. If it is a small object - even with the cascading deletes - I would expect it to be fast. The only real solution would be to execute custom SQL statements directly on your context.

Comment: This is why I was wondering if a https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#CascadeDelete would be more appropriate.  Tell the DB what to expect, then the Business Logic code could just delete the single PD specified, and the database deals with the rest.

Comment: @technorabble that might be, even though I still think that LINQ will have a hard time translating efficiently. But the best you can do, is to try and create a statement fire it against your DB and see the execution plan of the LINQ statement, to see if the SQL is more efficient.